# TimePicker Count Down in Milliseconds

Tags: ios, objective-c, countdown, timepicker, milliseconds

I have been trying for 2 days, searching high and low and cannot get the milliseconds to work.  The hours, mins & seconds work fine, but milliseconds won't.

I've made a lapCounter, which counts UP and has no issues with the milliseconds.

Here is the working code for the lapCounter, which counts UP and the milliseconds work:

```
    int hours = (UInt8)(elapsedTime /(60*60));
    int mins = (UInt8)(elapsedTime / 60.0);
    elapsedTime -= (mins * 60);
    int secs = (UInt8)(elapsedTime);
    elapsedTime -= (secs);
    int mms = (UInt8)(elapsedTime * 100);
```

But I can't make the TimePicker Count DOWN, work.

This is what I have for the TimePicker Count DOWN:

```
int afterRemainder;
int remainder;
NSTimeInterval countDownTime;
NSTimer *countDownTimer;
bool startCountDown;

- (IBAction)startCountDownButton:(id)sender {
    if (startCountDown == false) {
        countDownTime = (NSTimeInterval)_datePicker.countDownDuration;
        remainder = countDownTime;
        afterRemainder = countDownTime - remainder%60;

        countDownTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector:@selector(updateCountDown) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

        startCountDown = true;
}

-(void)updateCountDown {
    afterRemainder --;

    int hours = (int)(afterRemainder / (60 * 60));
    int mins = (int)(afterRemainder / 60) - (60 * hours);
    int secs = (int)(afterRemainder - (60 * mins) - (60 * hours * 60));
    int mms = (int)(afterRemainder - (3600 * secs) - (mins * 60));
    self.displayCountDown.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%02d", hours];
    self.displayCountDownMins.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@": %02d", mins];
    self.displayCountDownSecs.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%02d", secs];
    self.displayCountDownMMs.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@":%2d", mms];
}
```

Comment: Define "doesn't work". What exactly is the issue? Give clear examples in your question (not in comments).

Comment: @rmaddy hi thanks for posting.  The milliseconds don't count down in milliseconds.  Some crazy numbers come up and I've tried everything.

Comment: @rmaddy it's the math in the milliseconds that fails.

Comment: Why are your up and down calculations for hours, mins, secs, and mms so radically different? They should be identical.

Comment: I've tried that.  That's what I just don't get.  But the hours, secs and mins all work properly on the down.

Comment: Notice that on the down, there is a %60 at the start countdown method in the countDown%60;  if I take that out, it gets worst.

Comment: What value are you setting for `countDownDuration` initially?  Although the picker only shows hours and minutes, there are also seconds (take from the current time when the picker is initialised) so unless you set `countDownDuration` to a specific number of seconds (say 120 for 2 minutes), you will get an odd starting value

Comment: I took out the %60 from the countdown time = remainder, and used the same code from the up, and all times are wrong.

Comment: Ok, I'll look into that.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
@interface ViewController ()

@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UILabel *hours;
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UILabel *minutes;
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UILabel *seconds;
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UILabel *millisecs;

@property (nonatomic, readwrite) NSTimeInterval counter;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSTimer *timer;

@property (nonatomic, readwrite) int hoursInt;
@property (nonatomic, readwrite) int minutesInt;
@property (nonatomic, readwrite) int secondsInt;
@property (nonatomic, readwrite) int millisecsInt;

@end

@implementation ViewController

#define MS_COUNT_STEP 20.0 // Approx 50 fps

- (IBAction)countUpPressed:(id)sender {
    [self.timer invalidate];
    self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:MS_COUNT_STEP / 1000.0 target:self selector:@selector(countUp) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}

- (IBAction)countDownPressed:(id)sender {
    [self.timer invalidate];
    self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:MS_COUNT_STEP / 1000.0 target:self selector:@selector(countDown) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}

- (void)countUp {
    self.counter += (MS_COUNT_STEP / 1000.0);
}

- (void)countDown {
    self.counter -= (MS_COUNT_STEP / 1000.0);
}

- (void)setCounter:(NSTimeInterval)counter {
    _counter = counter;
    [self updateUI];
}

- (void)updateUI {
    NSTimeInterval counter = _counter;

    self.hoursInt = counter / 3600;
    counter -= ((int)self.hoursInt * 3600);

    self.minutesInt = counter / 60;
    counter -= ((int)self.minutesInt * 60);

    self.secondsInt = (int)counter;
    counter -= self.secondsInt;

    self.millisecsInt = counter * 1000;
}

- (void)setHoursInt:(int)value {
    if (value != _hoursInt) {
        _hoursInt = value;
        self.hours.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", value];
    }
}

- (void)setMinutesInt:(int)value {
    if (value != _minutesInt) {
        _minutesInt = value;
        self.minutes.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", value];
    }
}

- (void)setSecondsInt:(int)value {
    if (value != _secondsInt) {
        _secondsInt = value;
        self.seconds.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", value];
    }
}

- (void)setMillisecsInt:(int)value {
    if (value != _millisecsInt) {
        _millisecsInt = value;
        self.millisecs.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", value];
    }
}

@end
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the code, it does produce milliseconds, but I can't connect it to the datePicker.  I've added the code at the end, on how I've tried to connect it.

Comment: This is how I've tried to connect the datePicker to your "counter".

{
self.countDownTime = (NSTimeInterval)_datePicker.countDownDuration;
        remainder = self.countDownTime;
        _counter = self.countDownTime - remainder;

        self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:MS_COUNT_STEP / 1000.0 target:self selector:@selector(countDown) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

}

Comment: Wouldn't you just use: "self.counter = self.dataPicker.countDownDuration"?

Comment: Ok, I set it as suggested and it works! But it starts at above the actual time.  So if datePicker has 10:00, it will start at 10:00, but with 6 seconds on top.  So it has to go thru 6 seconds before it gets to where it should start, which is 9:59:59.  Any ideas?

Comment: Ah. You need to ignore the seconds component, as the UIDatePicker only has a resulotion of 1 minute. So: "self.counter = 60 * (int)(self.datePicker.countDownDuration / 60);"

Comment: DUDE, YOU ARE A GENIUS!!!  I owe you a beer, hell no, a Pint!  Thank you so much!! If you are in Los Angeles, let me know!

Comment: If you could mark the answer as correct, that's payment enough ;)

Answer (score 0):

Use CADisplayLink, instead NSTimer.

A CADisplayLink object is a timer object that allows your application to synchronize its drawing to the refresh rate of the display.

With [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 ...] the system can't draw the labels at that speed.